# How to test my tooltip component using Vue.js and Jest?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-component

I'm trying to test my tooltip component, but it seems it does not exist :cry:

My .html

```
        <div>
          <boxComponent>
            Some text
            <tooltipComponent
              @mouseover.native="handleHover(true)"
              @mouseleave.native="handleHover(false)"
            >This text appears on Hover</tooltipComponent>
          </boxComponent>
          <switchComponent button-type="button" :label="false" @change="activeFun" />
        </div>
```

My .js

```
methods: {
  handleHover (s) {
    this.onHoverTooltip = s
  },
}
```

My .spec.js

```
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)

//...

  it('should reveal tooltip\'s mesage', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(ozFilters, {
      propsData: {
        //others stuffs,
        label: false,
      },
      localVue,
      store,
      stubs: ['tooltipComponent', 'boxComponent', 'switchComponent'],
    })

    expect(wrapper.find('tooltipComponent-stub').exists()).toBeFalsy()

    // wrapper.vm.label = true
    wrapper.vm.handleHover(true)

    expect(wrapper.find('tooltipComponent-stub').exists()).toBeTruthy()
  })
```

I need to understand what should I do to test the tooltip component that is already a custom component.

Even without the `-stub` it does not work.

The error is occurring in this line `expect(wrapper.find('tooltipComponent-stub').exists()).toBeTruthy()` with says that the expect is false.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a couple of things that need to be fixed/clarified.

First of all, you are using `shallowMount` to create a component which you want to test, it stubs all custom components provided in tested component so you don't have to additionally use `stub` parameter to stub them, you can easily delete this: `stubs: ['tooltipComponent', 'boxComponent', 'switchComponent']`.

When you want to find specific component it's recommended to use [findComponent](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/findcomponent.html) instead of just `find`. (Using `find` to search for a component is actually deprecated). To properly identify component it's best to import it in your test file and use it in `findComponent` argument, something like this:

```js
import BoxComponent from 'path/to/BoxComponent'

it('lovely test', () => {
    wrapper.findComponent(BoxComponent)
})
```

After this your test should pass, but there are some things to consider like using `mount` instead of `shallowMount`. It's explained [here](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#common-tips), but to wrap it up, `mount` will render actual component with its children, where `shallowMount` stubs components inside tested component, so you are not testing the actual component but some "shadow" of its true nature. To see a difference between this functions I would recommend to create a `wrapper` with both functions and then see what [html()](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#html) will return from them.